# Saving to relational table Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

Basically I have a groups table with id and name,

I have another table with users_groups with id, group_id and user_id

I'm try to save when a user is created to the users_groups table, but when I use this code it saves what it can in the groups table. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Account controller (saving user to db and set group to id 1)

```
$user = User::create(array(
    'firstName' => $firstName,
    'lastName' => $lastName,
    'dateOfBirth' => $dateOfBirth,
    'gender' => $gender,
    'email' => $email,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => Hash::make($password),
    'code' => $code,
    'active' => 0
));


Group::create([

    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'group_id' => '1' //1 is not assigned

]);
```

Group Model

```
class Group extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('name');

    // DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS --------------------------------------------------
    // define a many to many relationship
    // also call the linking table
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_groups', 'group_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

User Model

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $fillable =array('email', 'username', 'password', 'password_temp', 'code', 'active', 'firstName','lastName','gender','dateOfBirth');
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    // Each User BELONGS to many Groups
    // Define our pivot table also
    public function groups() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group', 'users_groups', 'user_id', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All information about saving relations can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

You need `attach()`

```
$user = User::create(array(
    'firstName' => $firstName,
    // ...
));

$user->groups()->attach(1); // 1 being the group_id
```

Comment: i modifed it to that and i got an error of..... Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Comment: DB::table('users_groups')
   ->insert([

    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'group_id' => '1'

   ]);

Comment: Did that and it works but I'm guessing not the best way... sorry I'm pretty new to this framework.... first tryout